# How to locate binaries during make check?

Tags: autotools, automake

I'm having troubles running `make check` due to path issues. Currently my shell script (configured by autoconf) contains

```
prefix="@prefix@"
exec_prefix="@exec_prefix@"
PATH="@libexecdir@:$PATH"
```

it later expect to execute binary located in @libexecdir@. This works find after `make install`, but when it does not work is during `make check`. Because files are yet not installed, they are not at the expected location.

What is the correct solution to this? I must not be the first one to try to solve this...

Comment: By "my shell script" do you mean a script embodying one of your tests, or do you mean an installable component of your project that you are subjecting to test?  Or something else?

Comment: Installable component. One is installed as `bin_SCRIPTS = foo`, another as `libexec_SCRIPTS = bar` and I need to call `bar` from `foo`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, the correct thing to do is RTFM (as it usually is):

Quote from (emphasis mine): https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/autoconf.html#Installation-Directory-Variables

> Most of these variables have values that rely on prefix or exec_prefix. It is deliberate that the directory output variables keep them unexpanded: typically ‘@datarootdir@’ is replaced by ‘${prefix}/share’, not ‘/usr/local/share’, and ‘@datadir@’ is replaced by ‘${datarootdir}’.
>
> This behavior is mandated by the GNU Coding Standards, so that when the user runs:
>
> ‘make’
>
> she can still specify a different prefix from the one specified to configure, in which case, if needed, the package should hard code dependencies corresponding to the make-specified prefix.
>
> ‘make install’
>
> she can specify a different installation location, in which case the package must still depend on the location which was compiled in (i.e., never recompile when ‘make install’ is run). This is an extremely important feature, as many people may decide to install all the files of a package grouped together, and then install links from the final locations to there.
>
> In order to support these features, it is essential that datarootdir remains defined as ‘${prefix}/share’, so that its value can be expanded based on the current value of prefix.
>
> A corollary is that you should not use these variables except in makefiles. For instance, instead of trying to evaluate datadir in configure and hard-coding it in makefiles using e.g., ‘AC_DEFINE_UNQUOTED([DATADIR], ["$datadir"], [Data directory.])’, you should add -DDATADIR='$(datadir)' to your makefile's definition of CPPFLAGS (AM_CPPFLAGS if you are also using Automake).
>
> **Similarly, you should not rely on AC_CONFIG_FILES to replace bindir and friends in your shell scripts and other files**; instead, let make manage their replacement. For instance Autoconf ships templates of its shell scripts ending with ‘.in’, and uses a makefile snippet similar to the following to build scripts like autoheader and autom4te:
>
> ```
>  edit = sed \
>          -e 's|@bindir[@]|$(bindir)|g' \
>          -e 's|@pkgdatadir[@]|$(pkgdatadir)|g' \
>          -e 's|@prefix[@]|$(prefix)|g'
>
>  autoheader autom4te: Makefile
>          rm -f $@ $@.tmp
>          srcdir=''; \
>            test -f ./$@.in || srcdir=$(srcdir)/; \
>            $(edit) $${srcdir}$@.in >$@.tmp
>
>          chmod +x $@.tmp
>          chmod a-w $@.tmp
>          mv $@.tmp $@
>
>  autoheader: $(srcdir)/autoheader.in
>  autom4te: $(srcdir)/autom4te.in
> ```

Answer (score 2):

> I must not be the first one to try to solve this.

No, but although I'll describe some possibilities in a moment, there's no one true convention for approaching the issue.  And some projects simply *don't* solve it -- they either don't provide automated tests at all, or they design their test suite to run after installation.

> What is the correct solution to this?

It depends on the details of your program / script.  Programs that are highly inflexible about where to find external software on which they rely may be very difficult to test prior to installation.  Of course, it follows that if pre-installation testability is a project goal, then you must build some flexibility into the script with respect to how it locates the binary(-ies) it wants to run.

The most common forms for such flexibility are probably

- recognizing command-line options by which the binary's location can be overridden at run time, and / or
- recognizing environment variables that serve the same purpose.

Depending on the project, such an override capability might serve more use cases than just testing.

As long as we're talking about environment variables, though, the script *should not* rely on the executable search path to locate the wanted binary.  The libexec directory should not be in the path -- binaries there should be run only explicitly.  Even setting it internally in the script is not a sufficient solution because it may propagate from there to other programs the script runs.  Additionally, if for some reason the wanted binary is not in the libexec directory then you do not want to accidentally run a different binary that happens to have the same name.

Comment: `Even setting it internally in the script is not a sufficient solution because it may propagate from there to other programs the script runs.` - hm, you are right, did not occur to me